# How to change confluent rest proxy body data schema for producing messages

Tags: confluent-platform, confluent-rest-proxy

The confluent rest proxy documents suggest that to post a data it must be as such:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json" \
      --data '{"records":[{"value":{"name": "testUser"}}]}' \
      "http://localhost:8082/topics/jsontest"
```

namely, every post data must be wrapped inside the following schema:

```
{"records":[
    {"value":{<DATA>}}
]}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to change this schema? For instance, I might want to change records to log and include my data as inside an array as the value to the log as follows:

```
{"log": [<my_data>, <my_data>] }
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The API is defined in the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html#post--topics-(string-topic_name)) and states the format that your payload must take.

If you want to batch your records together you need to do so within the defined schema, e.g.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json" \
      --data '{ "records": [ { "value": { "name": "testUser1" } }, { "value": { "name": "testUser2" } } ] }' \
      "http://localhost:8082/topics/jsontest"
```

AFAIK the only way to support the schema you're talking about would be to modify [the source code](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest) yourself.